# WP Rocket - Optimize CSS delivery and Divi blog module problem

Tags: css, wordpress, optimization

Site URL: https://infomuhely.hu

I have encountered a known problem with Divi theme, when I started using WP Rocket to optimize my websites. The main problem as I mentioned in the title is between Optimize CSS delivery function and Divi's blog module (only when it is set to Grid).

At first I googled it and find an advice on [WP Rocket's blog](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/657-divi-theme#blog-module). After downloading and setting up correctly the add-on, nothing happened, besides it should exclude the main Divi style sheet.

I searched the internet and [find this article](https://www.mrkwp.com/2018/07/configure-wp-rocket-for-divi-and-gravity-forms/). And then I exclude the salvattore.min.js, but nothing happened. Interesting, but if I am logged in as administrator I can see the blog module in its perfect shape, but If I turn on "caching for logged-in users" function the blog module disappears.

I almost tried every combination to try solve this problem, but I have no success yet. I did find an alternative route: Changing the blog module to "Full width" and using the css [from this site](https://divibooster.com/show-archive-page-featured-images-on-left-of-post-extract/) have a quite good outcome. But I still looking for an answer, because there are some sites where I need to use "Grid" type of display.

Optimize CSS delivery has a huge impact on Google Insight score, that is the reason I don't want to let it go.